# simplifying a max operation

Tags: inequality

In  some derivation I arrived to I had reached the following assuming $\alpha,\beta >0$
 $$\max\{1,1+\beta \}\leq \max\{\alpha,\alpha+\beta\}$$

Obviously the following condition can be deduced
 $$1\leq\alpha$$

Is there any other condition?
Thanks

Comment: Notice that $\forall x\in \Bbb R\;\Big[\max\{x, x+\beta\} = x+\max\{0, \beta\}\Big]$ so the assumption $\alpha, \beta > 0$ is not even required.

Answer (score 2):

$\max\{1,1+\beta\}=1+\beta$ and $\max\{\alpha,\alpha+\beta\}=\alpha+\beta$. Thus, the inequality you have reached is 
$$1+\beta\le\alpha+\beta$$
which is equivalent to
$$1\le\alpha$$

Comment: I have edited my question...

Comment: I'm sorry. My former answer meant that some information about $\beta$ was needed, but I was wrong: the meaning of the inequality does not depend on $\beta$ (if $\beta$ were negative it would be easy to show the same conclusion: $1\le \alpha$).